# How to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N-2}{2}}(-1)^n(\frac{N-2n-1}{2n+1})\leq\frac{N\pi}{4}$ for even $N$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

For even $N$, I have calculated the value of the sum

$A_N=\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N-2}{2}}(-1)^n(\frac{N-2n-1}{2n+1})$

for several values of $N$ and it appears as though the sum is always less than $\frac{N\pi}{4}$ But I am having trouble proving it. Does anyone have any ideas for how to prove that for even $N$,

$\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N-2}{2}}(-1)^n(\frac{N-2n-1}{2n+1})\leq\frac{N\pi}{4}$?

Comment: If $N$ is a multiple of 4, then you can remove $2n+1$ from the numerator because $\sum(-1)^n\frac{2n+1}{2n+1}=0$.  Bring $N$ out the front, and you get partial sums of $1-1/3+1/5-1/7...$ which will be below the limit of $\pi/4$.

Comment: @Michael How does $\sum_{n=0}^{(N-2)/2}(-1)^n\frac{2n+1}{2n+1}=0$? Won't it be 1 for some $N$?

Comment: @Michael Don't worry, I understand! Any ideas for when N is not a multiple of 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $N=2M$ we have to prove:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{M-1}(-1)^n\left(\frac{2M}{2n+1}-1\right)=\frac{(-1)^M-1}{2}+2M\sum_{n=0}^{M-1}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\leq\frac{M\pi}{2}.\tag{1}$$
It is well known that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}\tag{2}$$
hence if $M$ is even we have:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{M-1}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}<\frac{\pi}{4}\tag{3}$$
while for odd $M$s we have:
$$ -\frac{1}{2M}+\sum_{n=0}^{M-1}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}<\frac{\pi}{4}\tag{3}$$
hence $(1)$ is proved.

Comment: The first term, for 0,1,0,1, should be negative, -1,0,-1,0,-1,0.  When $M$ is odd, how do you show the partial sum of $(-1)^n/(2n+1)$ is less than $1/2M$ above $\pi/4$?

Comment: @Micheal: the easiest way, IMHO, is to use the Taylor series with integral remainder. Fast and clean.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio (2) was not well known by me so thank you! And for the Taylor series, could you elaborate a little please? Also, shouldn't the first term be $\frac{(-1)^M-1}{2}$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm not sure how Taylor series come into this. Which function are you finding the Taylor series for?

Comment: @BenJames: $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n x^{2n},\qquad \arctan x=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\,x^{2n+1}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I still don't understand how this helps to show (3). $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is the derivative of $\arctan{x}$ and I can see now where (2) comes from. But I am still stuck for the odd values of $M$. Could you please explain a bit more? Where does the $\frac{1}{2M}$ come from?

Comment: @BenJames: for odd $M$s, $\frac{(-1)^M-1}{2}$ equals $-1$. When you divide it by $2M$, you get $-\frac{1}{2M}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio For odd $M$, $\sum_{n=0}^{M-1}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{M-2}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}+\frac{(-1)^{M-1}}{2(M-1)+1}<\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2M-1}$. I don't know what I am doing wrong...or where the Taylor remainder comes in?

Comment: @BenJames: right, now you just have to show that the same inequality holds with $\frac{1}{2M-1}$ replaced by $\frac{1}{2M}$. Use integral remainder.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am not seeing how to apply the integral remainder though?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I understand now - thanks!